# How to connect MySQL 8.0.x using Navicat?

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have installed MySQL 8.0.4, but my Navicat for MySQL can not connect it, the warning is:

> 1251  -  Client  does  not  support  authentication  protocol 
>   requested  by  server;  consider  upgrading  MySQL  client.

How do I fix it?

Comment: are you trying to direct access the DB or using tunnel SSH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your warning message it looks like that your Navicat do not support MySQL 8.0.4.

**Option 1**

Just to be clear, the version of MySQL that you updated to 8.0.4 was released at 2018-01-23 and latest version of Navicat was released 2017-05-31 so 99,99% sure that it wont support latest MySQL, so either downgrade to 5.7.x version or just wait next release of Navicat.

**Option 2**
Check if there is a client for MySQL which is alrady supporting version 8.0.4. Hint here - I'm using SequelPro and it is not supporting it also. Hint #2 MySQL Workbench releasing quite often, meaning the soonish support of latest mysql is quite possible for tham

**Option 3** 
You always have command line client, which is in some cases the best one, especially for learning reasons.

Regards

Comment: I see,Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RichardTian if you satisfied with my answer, mark it as useful :)